# Convert nn.Linear to nn.Conv1d

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

The format I want to output my model to doesn't support nn.Linear, so I'd like to change it to do the exact same thing but with nn.Conv1d.

My input is of shape (N, A, B) and I'd like to have a linear layer that transforms that into an output of shape (N, A, C). Previously, I was doing this with the layer `nn.Linear(B, C)`. I'm able to produce working code that has the correct dimensions by doing

```
t1 = t1.transpose(1,2)
conv = nn.Conv1d(
            in_channels=B,
            out_channels=C,
            kernel_size=1
        )
t2 = conv(t1)
t2 = t2.transpose(1,2)
```

Is this functionally equivalent to doing `t2 = nn.Linear(B,C)(t1)`?
If so, is there a better/less verbose way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is essentially doing the same thing.
Instead of transposing you could just add a trailing dummy dimension by doing

```
t1 = t1.unsqueeze(-1)
...
t2 = t2.squeeze(-1)
```

This has the advantage that the data doesn't have to be reordered, but the effect is probably negligible.